The coherence of physicalism: are there any solutions to Hempel's dilemma?
SEP presents the dilemma as follows:

4.3 Hempel’s dilemma
One might object that any formulation of physicalism which utilizes the theory-based conception will be either
trivial or false. Carl Hempel (cf. Hempel 1969, see also Crane and
Mellor 1990) provided a classic formulation of this problem: if
physicalism is defined via reference to contemporary physics, then it
is false — after all, who thinks that contemporary physics is
complete? — but if physicalism is defined via reference to a future or
ideal physics, then it is trivial — after all, who can predict what a
future physics contains? Perhaps, for example, it contains even mental
items. The conclusion of the dilemma is that one has no clear concept
of a physical property, or at least no concept that is clear enough to
do the job that philosophers of mind want the physical to play.
One response to this objection is to take its first horn, and insist
that, at least in certain respects contemporary physics really is
complete or else that it is rational to believe that it is (cf. Smart
1978, Lewis 1994 and Melnyk 1997, 2003). There is an element of truth
in this. It may be rational to believe that contemporary science is
true, even if not that it is complete. Nevertheless, it also seems
mistaken to define physicalism with respect to the physics that
happens to be true in this world. The reason is that whether a
physical theory is true or not is a function of the contingent facts;
but whether a property is physical or not is not a function of the
contingent facts. For example, consider medieval impetus physics.
Medieval impetus physics is false (though of course it might not have
been) and thus it is irrational to suppose it true. Nevertheless, the
property of having impetus — the central property that objects have
according to impetus physics — is a physical property, and a
counterfactual world completely described by impetus physics would be
a world in which physicalism is true. But it is hard to see how any of
this could be right if physicalism were defined by reference to the
physics that we have now or by the physics that happens to be true in
our world. (For development of this point, and for a dilemma that is
similar to Hempel’s but which casts the issue in modal rather than
temporal terms, see Stoljar 2010; for discussion, see Baltimore 2013,
Fiorese 2016)
A different response to Hempel’s dilemma is that what it shows, if it
shows anything, is that a particular proposal about how to define a
physical property — namely, via reference to physics at a particular
stage of its development — is mistaken. But from this one can hardly
conclude that we have no clear understanding of the concept at all. As
we have seen, we have many concepts that we don’t know how to analyze.
So the mere fact — if indeed it is a fact — that a certain style of
analysis of the notion of the physical fails does not mean that there
is no notion of the physical at all, still less that we don’t
understand the notion.
One might object that, while these remarks are perfectly true, they
nevertheless don’t speak to something that is right about Hempel’s
dilemma, namely, that for the theory-conception to be complete one
needs to know what type of theory a physical theory is. Perhaps one
might appeal here to the fact that we have a number of paradigms of
what a physical theory is: common sense physical theory, medieval
impetus physics, Cartesian contact mechanics, Newtonian physics, and
modern quantum physics. While it seems unlikely that there is any one
factor that unifies this class of theories, perhaps there is a cluster
of factors — a common or overlapping set of theoretical constructs,
for example, or a shared methodology. If so, one might maintain that
the notion of a physical theory is a Wittgensteinian family
resemblance concept. However, whether this is enough to answer the
question of what kind of theory a physical theory is remains to be
seen. (For further discussion of Hempel’s dilemma, see the papers in
Elpidorou 2018a.)

In short, either we define physicalism in terms of current physics, which is clearly imperfect and incomplete (e.g., The Crisis in String Theory is Worse Than You Think | Leonard Susskind), or we define physicalism in terms of a vague, idealized, hypothetical notion of physics that we will hopefully figure out in the future, but in that case we have no way to know in advance what such an idealized notion of physics will actually look like (e.g., perhaps it will include consciousness as fundamental, perhaps it will include spirits, etc.).
Is there any way out of this dilemma?

We already had a God of the Gaps, now we have a Dilemma of the Gaps..

You should know Leibniz is not a physicalist while a physicist whose ideas about both nonsensible infinitesimals ghosts criticized even by idealist Berkeley and potentials are still used in physics today widely, not unlike nonsensible metaphysical supersymmetry in String theory though its creator Susskind recently admitted its failure in our real world de Sitter space as in your linked reference...

Airplanes fly. The folks building and flying them aren't sitting around here.

Why would, and why would you expect anyone else to give credence to Hempel’s dilemma… at least as you describe it.
To me, that so far fails in simple logic, it isn't worthy of promotion to SE Philosophy

For people who reject the non-physical (i.e. physicalists), Hempel’s dilemma might not be a dilemma at all, and it's arguably shifting the burden of proof onto physicalists to define something they don't propose and don't accept (the non-physical, and how to differentiate that from the physical).

if physicalism is defined via reference to contemporary physics...
but if physicalism is defined via reference to a future or ideal physics...

I would say it's neither. It's a matter of what stuff is and what exists, not a matter of what we know or can know (although the two certainly go hand in hand, since we may or may not know what stuff is and what exists).
As per another answer of mine, one might consider the physical to be the place where all the things are that we can experience (directly or indirectly) with our basic senses - see, hear, smell, taste, touch (yes, this may be a bit fuzzy with proposed non-physical claims, as addressed in that answer). Physicalists don't see a reason to think there's any other place, and tend to reject claims that can't reasonably be argued to be in this place, in cases where we don't have empirical evidence for such things. This typically includes rejecting claims of gods and ghosts and souls and the afterlife and psychic powers and such (which tend to all be proposed to be outside of empirical investigation, to varying degrees).
Note, however:

There may exist things in this place that we can never know, e.g. distant planets beyond our ability to ever sense, given the laws of physics. That wouldn't make those non-physical.
This includes updating our knowledge as we gain more evidence. 1000 years ago, people may not have been justified in accepting the existence of quantum fields, because they lacked the supporting evidence. But now we have the evidence, so we're justified in accepting it. Physicalists wouldn't say any categorical switch happened there from non-physical to physical. If someone proposed it 1000 years ago, it would've still been a physical claim, just an unjustified one.
This does not preclude someone proposing claims beyond empirical investigation, but it would place the burden on them to propose another means of investigation that would lead to accepting that claim, as well as providing a justification for why that means should be used (e.g. is it reliable?).

Hempel's dilemma presupposes that there is at least 1 more place or 1 more category of things. Otherwise it's asking physicalists to differentiate "the physical" from... nothing? Physicalists don't accept any additional categories beyond the physical, so it doesn't make much sense to ask them to draw a line between said categories, to explain what would fit into "the physical" and what would not.
In reality, the lack of clarity in what is meant by "physical" is more of a problem for those proposing that it is one of multiple categories of things. Physicalists just have that being everything that exists, so there's nothing to differentiate it from.
Another way of thinking about it
One might consider "physicalism" to be shorthand for: not accepting the existence or truth of gods, angels, demons, djinns, heaven, hell, valhalla, limbo, purgatory, the underworld, the astral plane, the thirteen heavens, baralku, barzakh, diyu, the spirit world, spirits, ghosts, telekinesis, transcendent souls, out of body experiences, "essences" of materials, levitation, clairvoyance, precognition, etc.
If one were to consider it as such, it would be much more obvious that Hempel's dilemma doesn't apply: there is no category, there is just a list of claims. Physicalists aren't the ones putting all those things into a category, other than the category of "things which we lack good reason to believe exist". People who accept those claims are typically the ones labelling it as non-physical, to try to explain why there is a lack of supporting evidence for those claims (without accepting that those things just don't exist). But of course one can also discuss any one of those things to consider whether there is or is not good reason to believe it exists.
But listing off all those items would take a while. It's far shorter to just label that "physicalism".
On that note (and as alluded to above), we can also somewhat consider physicalism to involve only accepting existence claims which are supported by empirical evidence (roughly speaking). But this would also entail rejecting the existence of proposed "physical" things that either don't exist or which we don't have enough evidence for yet - this is not a bad thing, but it might make physicalism less specific to the claims above, for which there might be some benefit to adopting the physicalism label in objection to (since many people believe such claims), to say that empirical investigation is really the only reliable means of investigation we have for existence claims.
Metaphysical or methodological?
There is a somewhat blurry line between physicalism as a metaphysical position (what is the nature of reality) versus a methodological position (how we approach evaluating claims).
We developed the methodology of using empirical evidence and rejecting things without empirical evidence. That leads to a metaphysical position where the nature of reality is said to just be this place we experience with our senses (existing in whatever form that it does), because we have no means of investigating anything that may be beyond that, and thus we have no reasonable way to conclude that such things exist.

"But listing off all those items would take a while." - In fact it would be impossible, since the list is arguably infinite. Instead, it would be much more efficient to define the epistemological methodology used to decide what sorts of things are believed to exist and sorts of things would fail to be accepted to exist. However, I feel that this kind of move would shift the definition of physicalism from something metaphysical to something epistemological.

Given that many physicalists dismiss the concept of the metaphysical, that shift seems entirely justified. As is often the case, the problem arises when trying to define X in terms of Y when X does not accept being a subset of Y.

@keshlam Physicalism is a metaphysical view. From SEP: "Physicalism is, in slogan form, the thesis that everything is physical. The thesis is usually intended as a metaphysical thesis, parallel to the thesis attributed to the ancient Greek philosopher Thales, that everything is water, or the idealism of the 18th Century philosopher Berkeley, that everything is mental. The general idea is that the nature of the actual world (i.e. the universe and everything in it) conforms to a certain condition, the condition of being physical."

@user: note "usually" and "in slogan form" , and ask "intended by who  and for what definition of metaphysical?"" I stand by my answer; you are relying upon an oversimplification and a characterization from outside.

@keshlam How would you define physicalism then? Wikipedia also uses the word "metaphysical": The use of "physical" in physicalism is a philosophical concept and can be distinguished from alternative definitions found in the literature (e.g., Karl Popper defined a physical proposition as one that can at least in theory be denied by observation). A "physical property", in this context, may be a metaphysical or logical combination of properties which are physical in the ordinary sense.

It is common to express the notion of "metaphysical or logical combination of properties" using the notion of supervenience: A property A is said to supervene on a property B if any change in A necessarily implies a change in B.

As you say, supervenence does not require metaphysics,  though it can be applied to metaphysics. It works perfectly well in the physical domain.

Metaphysics is, by definition, that which goes beyond the physical. While physicalism is theory above the physical layer, if depends only upon the physical, not the metaphysical; if anything it is the null hypothesis for the later.

@keshlam I'm not sure what definition of metaphysics you are using. Wikipedia suggests this definition: Metaphysics is the branch of philosophy that examines the basic structure of reality. That's 100% compatible with physics. According to your definition, concepts like metaphysical naturalism should be an oxymoron (a contradiction in terms).

It is not "shifting the burden of proof" on a claimant who says "everything is X" to ask define "X" and define "non-X".  The shifting the burden is when the advocate of "everything is X" demands a challenger provide the definitions.  Hempel's dilemma just points out that when physicalists are challenged, they uniformly fail at doing this defining.  The complaint in this post that there is no need to provide such a definition is both shifting the burden of proof, and evasion fallacies. An "answer" that has two fallacies, and instead attacks non-physicalists doesn't show physicalist coherence!

@Dcleve In terms of what is meant by physicalism and how it defines the physical, I'll just leave this answer and my linked answer which explains exactly that to stand by their own merits. It's up to you whether you'd accept this clarification of what physicalism is, or whether you'll just keep insisting that physicalists explain themselves (despite having an explanation right in front of you) and twisting their position into something that it's not so you can ask them to explain something they don't even accept.

@user80226 Physics examines the basic structure of reality. Metaphysics would be the study of Physics: the study of the examination of the basic structure of reality.

With the same reasoning we can say that the idea of fish is false.
Our current understanding of fish is incomplete. There are many species still unknown to science. So until we have a full catalogue of all the fish in all the oceans, we have not a well-defined idea what a fish could be. So the idea of fish is a false idea. If we have catalogued all the species of fish, then the idea of fish is trivial. After all, who knows what kind of exotic fish we may find. We might even find out that humans and elephants are also fish after some kind..
And indeed: fish don't exist..

I'd give you additional points for "fish didn't exist". It's a lesson many of us could benefit from remembering more often, myself included.

"What the heck is 'physical'?"

You present the following as a creating a dilemma:

in that case we have no way to know in advance what such an idealized notion of physics will actually look like

One way out of the issue is to deny that the above quote is a problem and accept that we do not know how our conceptions of physics will evolve in the face of new observations as time goes by.

"Inquiring minds want to know"
